# Symfony - Form is not submit

Tags: forms, symfony, submit

I work with Symfony to build and send a contact form by mail. 
I use swiftMailer.

The problem is that my form is not submitted. 
So, my swiftmailer can't work because the isSumbitted will stay at false and $mailer->send(message) will not be activate

My controller :

```
public function index (Request $request, Swift_Mailer $mailer)
    {

        $form = $this->createForm(ContactType::class);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) { 
            $contactData = $form->getData();
            $name = $contactData['name'];
            $content = $contactData['message'];
            $email = $contactData['email'];
            $entreprise = $contactData['entreprise'];
            $zip = $contactData['zip'];


            $message = (new Swift_Message('Vous avez un nouveau message sur le site AMC Industrie.fr'))
                ->setFrom('test@example.com')
                ->setTo('test@gmail.com')
                ->setSubject('Demande d\'information')
                ->setCharset('utf-8')
                ->setContentType('text/html')
                ->setBody(
                    "
                    <p> Vous avez reçu un message de <strong>$name</strong>, de l'entreprise <strong>$entreprise</strong>
                    <br>(code postal : $zip ) <br>
                    Son email est : <strong>$email</strong>. </p>

                    <p> Son message :</p>
                    <p>$content
                    </p>
                    "
                )
            ;

            $mailer->send($message);

            return $this->redirectToRoute('map_contact');
        }

        return $this->render('contact/map_contact.html.twig', [
            'form' => $form->createView()
        ]);
    }
```

My Form :

```
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name',TextType::class, 
                ['label'=>false,
                'constraints' => new NotBlank,
                'attr' => [
                    'class'=> 'form-control',
                    'placeholder' => 'Nom et prénom',
                    ]
                ])

            ->add('email',EmailType::class, 
                ['label'=>false,
                'constraints' => new NotBlank,
                'attr' => [
                    'class' => 'form-control',
                    'placeholder' => 'adresse e-mail' 
                    ]
                ])
            ->add('entreprise',TextType::class,
            ['label'=>false,
                'constraints' => new NotBlank,
                'attr' => [
                    'class'=> 'form-control',
                    'placeholder' => 'Nom de votre entreprise'
                    ]
                ])
            ->add('zip',NumberType::class,
            ['label'=>false,
                'constraints' => new NotBlank,
                'attr' => [
                    'class'=> 'form-control',
                    'placeholder' => 'Code postal'
                    ]
                ])
            ->add('message',TextareaType::class,
            ['label'=>false,
                'constraints' => new NotBlank,
                'attr' => [
                    'class'=> 'form-control',
                    'placeholder' => 'Décrivez-nous votre projet'
                    ]
                ])
            ->add('save', SubmitType::class, 
            ['label' => 'Envoyer', 
                'attr'=> [
                    //'class' => 'waves-effect waves-light btn-large btn btn-primary mt-1 mb-5 lift',
                    'id' => 'form-submit'
                ]])

        ;
    }
```

My template :

```
<form>
              {{ form_start(form) }}
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group mb-5">
                                {{form_label(form.name, 'Nom et prénom')}}
                                {{form_widget(form.name)}}

                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group mb-5">                      
                                {{form_label(form.email, 'Email') }}
                                {{form_widget(form.email)}}
                            </div>
                           <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group mb-5">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group mb-5">
                                {{form_label(form.entreprise, 'Entreprise')}}
                                {{form_widget(form.entreprise)}}
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group mb-5">
                                {{form_label(form.zip, 'Code Postal')}}
                                {{form_widget(form.zip)}}
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group mb-5">  
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                {{form_label(form.message, 'Comment pouvons-nous vous aider ?')}}
                                {{form_widget(form.message)}}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div> <!-- / .row -->

                    <div class="row justify-content-center">
                        <div class="col-auto py-5">
                            <!-- Submit -->
                            <div>
                             {{form_widget(form.save)}}   
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div> 

                {{ form_end(form) }}
                </form>
```

My debug tool : 
Form in get parameter OK. I have all my input with informations.

Debug tool - get parameters:

[image: screenshot debug tool]

BUT 
there is not sumbitted data. `form is not submit`

debug tool - form is not submit:

[image: screenshot debug tool]

I don't understand where is my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it's resolved !

The problem : I already have a html balise for my form, in my template. 
When I delete , it's ok !